# $em->remove() symfony2 erasing all rows

Tags: symfony, doctrine-orm

I have an issue when erasing something from a BD.

The problem is that it not only erase the object i looked for (using findOneBy), but all the objects related to the principal id.

//---Controller

```
$new = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
$OBJcar = $new->getRepository('SomeOtherBundle:CarEntityClass')
    ->findOneBy(array('idOwner' => $idowner, 'idCar' => $idcar));
if($OBJcar){
  $new->remove($OBJcar);
  $new->flush();
  $msj="The car for an specific owner has been erased.";
}
```

//---Profiler (Query)

```
"START TRANSACTION"
  Parameters: { }
  Time: 0.22 ms
DELETE FROM schema.CarTable WHERE id_owner = ?
  Parameters: ['123456']
  Time: 0.63 ms
"COMMIT"
  Parameters: { }
  Time: 0.63 ms
```

How to erase the one row i am getting from the db?

Comment: Everything looks correct..  You're not accidently using a `cascade remove` or `cascade all` anywhere in your configs, are you?

Comment: I have a composite primary key on the table. The relations look like this: 
    CREATE TABLE schema.car
    (
    id_car bigint NOT NULL,
    id_owner bigint NOT NULL,
    CONSTRAINT car_pkey PRIMARY KEY (id_car, id_owner),
    CONSTRAINT car_person_fk FOREIGN KEY (id_owner)
      REFERENCES schema.persons (id) MATCH SIMPLE
      ON UPDATE NO ACTION ON DELETE NO ACTION,
    CONSTRAINT car_type_fk FOREIGN KEY (id_car)
      REFERENCES schema.cartype (id) MATCH SIMPLE
      ON UPDATE CASCADE ON DELETE CASCADE
    );

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use DQL

```
$query = $em->createQuery('DELETE SomeOtherBundle:CarEntityClass c WHERE c.idOwner = 4 AND c.id = 10');
$query->execute();
```

This will remove only single car with ID 10 and owner with ID 4.

Answer (score 34):

I voted down the answer above, because I'm tired of people using string DQLs.
It's not standartized, non-object oriented(even though in background dql operates with objects), it doesn't use caching mechanisms query builder provides, it's non-flexible and simply looks unclean.

Here is the "right way"(IMHO):

1. You add the repository class for entity
2. You add the method you need with a query builder in it
3. You call the method while passing parameters needed for specific REPOSITORY OBJECT ORIENTED ACTION
4. You get an easy-to-handle result

Here's the code:

```
namespace ProjectName\BundleName\Repository;
use Doctrine\ORM\EntityRepository;

class CarRepository extends EntityRepository
{
    public function deleteCarWithOwner($ownerId,$carId)
    {
        $isDeleted = $this->createQueryBuilder("car")
            ->delete()
            ->where('car.id  = :carId')->setParameter("carId", $carId)
            ->andWhere('car.idOwner = :ownerId')->setParameter("ownerId", $ownerId)
            ->getQuery()->execute();

        return $isDeleted;
    }
}
```

Also, refer to http://doctrine-orm.readthedocs.org/en/latest/reference/query-builder.html for query builder details. There are a lot of "pros" and I see no "cons" for using builder.

**LATE UPDATE**

Also, a lot of Doctrine's entity events are not dispatched when using DQL.

Comment: Actually, QueryBuilder is conditionally constructing a DQL query in several steps :D

Comment: I never said it wasn't.

Comment: This was only a fast example, your code is doing same stuff and it actually generate DQL at the end. Question was not about "clean solution" but about "how to delete rows from database". What is the best way to construct this DQL is out of the scope of this question it might be queryBuilder but it also might be something else. You can't say that query builder is the only solution here cuz you dont know use case.

Comment: It's not the only solution, but it's the better solution for reasons i described earlier. And IMHO it is very important to give clean, best versions of answers you can. People will google this question, they will look at this answer and will use it and not feel very concerned about code maintainability and flexibility. This way, when they need to change or add some logic or just improve upon it, then with MY answer they can do it easily and NOT google additional question.

Comment: How could you be sure that solution is better if you dont know any thing about use case?

Comment: Use case is in question and that's not the point. I wrote to you the point.

Comment: Might be worth mentioning too that if calling this from outside of a EntityRepository class, queryBuilder will need a 'from' context: ->from('AppBundle:Supercar','car')

Comment: It should be this: setParameter("id", $carId)